# VBA - validating slide against master theme

Tags: vba, powerpoint

We have a list of power point template with  master slide themes and we distribute this it to all our users, everything works fine if they use they use the theme and they don't change any font, font size or color. But the problem is if they change the font, font size etc,  how do we know which shape or text the user changed, basically need to validate the slide against master slide theme.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your question is that you haven't indicated what you've tried, or where you've looked for an answer. That's why you would have attracted a downvote. (Wasn't me, incidentally, but I've seen that happen before.)

When you're asking a question it's also important to pay close attention to the suggested topics which will update as you type; more than once I've spent time searching for an answer, have given up and was about to ask a question here, and then found exactly what I was looking for in the suggested answers meaning that I didn't have to ask at all. In this case it would be worth checking out the suggested answer:

[How to detect Theme fonts in Powerpoint 2007 VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563086/how-to-detect-theme-fonts-in-powerpoint-2007-vba?rq=1)

which may not give you exactly what you want, but will give you a place to start.