# How can I detect (and change) whether the font used in Charts in Excel and PowerPoint will follow the style or have been specified by a user?

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, vsto, powerpoint

When a chart is copied from Excel to PowerPoint, if the fonts on the Axis have been changed due to the style or theme applied in Excel, then they will normally change to be consistent with whichever theme is applied in PowerPoint (which is good). However, when the font (possibly formatting in general) has been overridden by a user, that the user specified font is the one used.

Writing code to detect what the default font is and apply it probably isn't that tricky, but I'd rather apply the theme font in a way that will match subsequent theme changes. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

I'm using C#, but am familiar with VBA and the object model is more or less identical in both, so approaches in either language should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

After a little more digging, setting any font to a theme font looks like it can be accomplished by using the special font names comprised of:

- `+mj` or `+mn` for heading or body fonts respectively
- `-lt`, `-ea`, or `-cs` for latin, east asian, or complex script fonts respectively

So for my purposes, if I just assign all heading-like shapes' font properties to have `font.name = "+mn-lt"` then I accomplish what I need to, i.e. the font will match the theme and reflect subsequent theme changes.

NB that detecting whether this actually is already the case, since the font can be assigned either using the special font name or the actual font name, is a difficult problem (addressed [elsewhere on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563086/how-to-detect-theme-fonts-in-powerpoint-2007-vba)). Thankfully, I don't have to worry too much about this...

Comment: FWIW, it might be enough to look at the font's .NameComplexScript property.  I haven't done any extensive testing on this but if it's e.g. +mj-cs it seems likely that it's a theme font; if it's just Calibri or whatever, it's a user applied/non-theme font.

Comment: Does `.NameComplexScript` actually retain `+mj-cs`? For font names, it looks like most of the time (except sometimes) they get converted from these into the actual font names. If that's not the case with any of the fontname properties, that could prove quite useful.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "retain", but if, for example, you add text as Calibri Body or Heading and text as just Calibri, then query the Font.Name.ComplexScript property for each, all of the Body/Heading formatted text will return +mn-cs or +mj-cs, where the regular text will return "Calibri".

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant - what I'm used to is `.Name = "+mn-lt"; WriteLine(.Name) // Calibri`